# How to deal with sharing deep-linked sites URLs?

Tags: parsing, sharing, deep-linking

I made a site which can be browsed both as non-deep linked version for non-javascript users (`somesite.com?state`) and a deep-link version for javascript-enabled users (`somesite.com#state`). ***Note***: both of these versions give the same content except in one version, the content is populated by PHP, and in other by javascript.

It works perfectly however when a javascript-enabled user browses the site and wants to share a link on Facebook such as (`somesite.com#someotherstate`), the Facebook can't parse the proper content of the page since it can't deal with hash parameters for deep-linking.

So, other then putting a separate "Share" button on the page which will give explicitly a non-deep linked version of the URL (`somesite.com?someotherstate`) for the user to copy and share on Facebook, how does the industry go about with this issue?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that Facebook implemented Google Ajax methodology. Can't find official statement though.